# java scanner.nextLine error: no line found

Tags: java, bash, terminal, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read two line from a file.
Here is my code (test.java):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        f();
        f();
    }
    static void f() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        str = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

This is my terminal when is try to read input from file:

```
$ cat>inp
abc
def
^C
$ javac test.java && java test<inp
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at test.f(test.java:12)
    at test.main(test.java:7)
```

This is my terminal when I try to read input from keyboard:

```
$ javac test.java && java
abc
def
$
```

there is no problem when reading from keyboard but at the first case I get runtime error.
what is the problem?

**P.S. by "reading from file" I mean reading input from a file by using '<' in a linux terminal.sorry for my mistake.**

Comment: Is there a space between test and <inp  in `java test<inp `

Comment: Where is your file? You do not seem to be reading any file like you are stating. You are simply getting user input via scanner.

Comment: by "reading from file" I mean reading input from a file in linux terminal by using '<'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with Scanner input stream, so make the Scanner public as follows,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        f();
        f();
    }
    static void f() {
        String str;
        str = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: is above code supports to read data from file  "I am trying to read two line from a file"

Comment: This solves my problem. but what was the problem with Scanner input stream?

Comment: @Dharmik yes we can read a data from file just change the inputstream in scanner constructor

Comment: @user175023 that's because the Scanner while initializing with inputstream it will go through the inputstream and buffers it, so when you are accessing the same stream it seems empty.